# Auto complete on Large data set

Tags: mongodb, autocomplete, nosql

I'm writing a project where I need to do an autocomplete on a data set that has 5 milion objects (schema is different for objects).

My first thought was to do SQL, but since Schema is changing it will not be fast
So I thought about MongoDB.

Two questions: 
1 - do you have sample code that's working that I can use?
2- is Mongo the best solution in place? will it be fast? is there another NoSQL database that I can use instead?

Answer (score 0):

If the time is critical and you wish to have the fastest database than [Redis](http://redis.io/) may be the database you are looking for. Here is a link to the [Auto complete blog post using Redis](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html).

[MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/) is a great database and includes many great feature so it may be a good choice either.

Comment: Thanks!! do you happen to have some sample code that pulls data from a redis database as auto-complete?

Comment: I added a link into the answer so try that it will be very helpful.